# Why is cin.getline() skipping the first word in each line?

Tags: c++, cin

I am trying to display the text of a command line inputted text file line by line. But for some reason, it skips the first word in each line after the first line.

code:

```
using std::cout;  
using std::cin;  
using std::endl;  

int main (int args, char* argv[])  
{   
 char x[100];  
 char y[100];  
 char z[100];  
 cin.getline(x,100) >> argv[2];  
 cin.getline(y,100) >> argv[2];  
 cin.getline(z,100) >> argv[2];  
 cout << x <<endl;  
 cout << y <<endl;  
 cout << z <<endl;  
 return 1;  
}
```

running  ./a.out < moby.txt
displays this:

```
CHAPTER 1. Loomings. 

me Ishmael. Some years ago--never mind how long precisely--having  
or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on
```

but the first three lines in moby.txt is this:

```
CHAPTER 1. Loomings.

Call me Ishmael. Some years ago--never mind how long precisely--having  
little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on
```

The code is omitting "Call" and "little".
I feel like this is an \n error but i have no idea how to fix it. 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: A very inventive use of the language cin.getline(y,100) >> argv[2];. I will have to remember that for the next time I really **want** to skip something at the start of each line. My coworkers will never guess what it does!

Comment: Why are you reading into `argv`?!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cin.getline(x,100) >> argv[2];
```

You read a line (or the first 99 characters of the line) into `x`.  Then you skip any whitespace and read the next word into `argv[2]`.  The first words are ending up there.

Why are you using `>> argv[2]`?  What are you possibly trying to do with this?  `argv[2]` may not exist and even if it does, you don't have any control over the size of the character array pointed to by `argv[2]`, so your chances of overrunning that array are quite high.

Rather than using `char` arrays directly for this, use `std::getline` with `std::string` to read lines into `std::string` objects:  it is much easier to write correct code this way.  For example,

```
std::string x;
if (!std::getline(std::cin, x)) {
    // handle input error
}
```

Comment: @user646651:  What exactly do you think the `>> argv[2]` is doing and why have you written it?

Comment: I meant argv[2] to be the moby.txt file that is inputted from command line argument. So I meant for that line of code to read in the moby.txt file into the cin.getline(x,100).

Comment: @user646651:  No.  `argv[2]` is a `char*`.  The `>> argv[2]` skips any whitespace characters then reads the next word from the stream (`std::cin` in this case) into the character array pointed to by that `char*`.  The contents of `moby.txt` are available via `std::cin`:  that's what the `< moby.txt` on the command line does.

Answer (score 1):

@James McNellis has already pointed to the basic problem. My advice would be:

1. Don't use the member-function form of `getline`.
2. Don't mix `getline` and `>>` in the same statement.
3. Use a loop.

Comment: In general, be extremely cautious about mixing `getline` and `>>` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I find the other C++ getline to be easier and safer to use;

```
string str;
getline (cin,str);
```

will slurp the entire line and put it into a string, which you can then play with via the many fine string methods, or stringstream if you want to do I/O on parts of the string.

Comment: Normally that's what I would do but unfortunately, I have to use C style strings for this project.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I chose to do to make sure I am not missing any words or letters when I Use `getline`:

```
cout << "\nEnter some words: ";

while (getline(cin,myString)){
       getline(cin,myString);
       break;
};
```

Comment: thanks for the edit. first time post. Just started with Vs code two days ago. I was having so much trouble using getline, until I figured this use out. I didnt find it anywhere else, Just kept trying different things until something worked... Still need to learn how you highlighted the getline, and why the spaces needed to be removed. I ask because when posting it said to indent 8 spaces exactly to turn it into code.